# java how to overload run() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some code like this, How Can I let the two run() methods run in different thread with start() method?

```
 public class Test extends Thread{
   @override
   public void run(){
        //do something

   }
   public void run(int i){
        //do something

   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test test=new Test();
     // test.start()
     // How Can I let the two run() methods run in different thread?

 }

}
```

Comment: These are methods, not functions; it is `run(),` not `Run(),` and `@Override,`not `@override.`

Comment: `()->testInstance.run()` in one thread and `()->testInstance.run(...)` in the next thread

Comment: Like every other method, but `start0()` executes the `run()` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want two separate threads, and you only need to implement `Runnable`. Extending thread means you want to change something in a `Thread`'s behaviour, which you don't.

Each thread will be doing something else so two `Runnable` implementations, `Task1` and `Task2`:

```
class Task1 implements Runnable (){
    public run(){
        System.out.println("Runnable 1");
    }
}

class Task2 implements Runnable (){
    public run(){
        System.out.println("Runnable 2");
    }
}

// create two threads, one for each task
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task1());
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Task2());

// start the threads (should print the two messages)
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

To have different arguments for different `Runnable` implementations use the constructor like this:

```
class ParamTask implements Runnable (){
    String someArg;
    public ParamTask(String someArg){
        this.someArg = someArg;
    }    

    public run(){
        System.out.println("Runnable argument was: " + this.someArg);
    }
}

Thread argThread = new Thread(new ParamTask("this is a message"));

argThread.start();
```

Comment: You probably want to create a parameterized constructor for the `Task`, and store the data in the object's state. You can not override or implement the function if it's not with the same signature.

Comment: @Jason Z No, because you call the start() method and not run().

Comment: ok..actually I want pass one parameter to run() function, but it seems like t1.start() cant do that

Comment: Try using the constructor to pass an argument for the task you're creating. Store that argument and use it in `run`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you're free to overload the run() method in your Thread
subclass.

```
public class FirstThread extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstThread ft1= new FirstThread();
        ft1.start(); // Seperate call stack
        ft1.run("With parameter"); // same call stack
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread is running");
    }
    public void run(String s){
        System.out.println("Overloaded Thread is running " +s );
    }
}
```

The overloaded run(String s) method will be ignored by the Thread class unless you call it yourself. The Thread class expects a run() method with no arguments, and it will execute this method for you in a separate call stack
after the thread has been started.
With a run(String s) method, the Thread class won't call the method for you, and even if you call the method directly yourself, execution won't happen in a new thread of execution with a separate call stack. 
It will just happen in the same call stack as the code that you made the
call from, just like any other normal method call.

Source : SCJP 1.6 Kathy Siera (Chapter 9 : Threads ,Section : Defining a Thread)

Now for your requirement use two class implement Runnable Interface and call 2 threads on separate call stack. With any one thread call run(String s) method which will execute your method on different call stack.

```
public class SeacondThreadRunnable {

public static void main(String[] a){

    Thread myThread1= new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    Thread myThread2= new Thread(new MyRunnable2());
    myThread1.start();
    myThread2.start();
 }
}
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Runnable run method called " +Thread.currentThread().getName());

    run(" Overloaded Thread is running " );  // calling overloaded run method
}
public void run(String s){
    System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + s);
 } 
}
class MyRunnable2 implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Runnable run method called " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
 }
}
```